# Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'string'

Tags: c#

I am asking this question because I have minimal understanding of the c sharp language and the Object-oriented paradigm. The following program was created, based on a few youtube videos and programming articles, from stack-overflow and various other sources.

```
 case "-":
                textBox.Text = (valor - Double.Parse(textBox.Text).ToString());
                break;
            case "*":
                textBox.Text = (valor * Double.Parse(textBox.Text).ToString());
                break;
            case "/":
                textBox.Text = (valor / Double.Parse(textBox.Text).ToString());
```

The following code segment is giving me the following errors 
    Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'string'
for the 3 cases

Thank you 
Any sort of help and advice is more than welcome

Comment: Use `textBox.Text = (valor / Double.Parse(textBox.Text)).ToString();`
This way you first divide, then make a string. Same with all other operations.

Answer (score 2):

You got misplaced `.ToString()`. move all of `.ToString()`s after `)`.
Like this:

`textBox.Text = (valor - Double.Parse(textBox.Text)).ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the decimal value out of your textbox

```
Double.Parse(textBox.Text)
```

Then calling ToString() afterwards (effectively un-parsing your decimal). You are getting an error because you are trying to subtract a string:

```
Double.Parse(textBox.Text).ToString()
```

From your valor decimal

Answer (score 0):

`Double.Parse(textBox.Text)` returns a double but then you are calling `ToString()` which returns a string.

So you have `textBox.Text = <double> - <string>`

Comment: Actually I think they just need to move it outside the parenthesis so that they will convert the result of the subtraction to a `string`.